# How to purge Android Work Manager cancelled threads

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have an issue with cancelling android work manager tasks in my current android application.

I employ work manager to execute background work. The user can cancel the current executing task fine, however it seems the default thread pool eventually runs out of valid threads as even though I can see the worker Running, the doWork method is never called.

I proved this (I believe), by initialising the work manager with a fixed thread pool of size 2 and once I have cancelled two workers subsequent workers doWork method never executes.

How can I purge the work mangers thread pool of cancelled threads to allow subsequent work to execute?

Comment: perhaps https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher thanks for this "pointer" however currently my App employs RxJava to choreograph my network and database calls so I believe switching to coroutines is going to mean replacing all my Rx chains with coroutines.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Can you please open an issue on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) with the required reproduction steps?
Please add the WorkManager version you're using and which device/OS version you're seeing this behavior.